# How to call a method from the class above?

Tags: java, methods

How can I call a method from the superclass from within the subclass?

This is an example of what I try to do, not the real class (to keep it simple)

```
public class Road {
    private Lane lane1 = new Lane();
    private Lane lane2 = new Lane();
    private int activeLane = 1;

    public void switchLanes(){
        if(activeLane == 1){
            activeLane = 2;
            lane2.go();
        }else if(activeLane == 2){
            activeLane = 1;
            lane1.go();
        }

    }
}

public class Lane {
    public void go(){
        driveLane();

        // here I want to call the method switchlane in the Road class to create a "loop"
    }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?
I know it is possible to just do it with a loop in the Road class, but that will create issues later on.

Comment: Don't understand the question.  Your code example does not contain any classes with a superclass/subclass relationship (there is no inheritance, only composition).  But if it did, you simply declare a method to be virtual and then you can call the superclass' implementation from the subclass through polymorphism.

Comment: The initialization of the lanes are incorrect. Watch your spelling.

Comment: You could pass an instance of the road as a parameter  `lane.go(Road road)`
then in go you just call `road.switchLanes()`
Not sure if this is considered politically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a (non-static) method of the `Road` class from the `Lane` class, you must have a reference to an instance of `Road`.

Let's get such a reference in the `Lane` constructor:

```
public class Lane {
    private Road road;

    public Lane(Road road) {
        this.road = road;
    }

    public void go(){
        // Here you can call methods of Road
        road.switchLanes();
    }
}
```

Now you have to make some changes in the `Road` class:

```
public class Road {
    private Lane lane1 = new Lane(this);
    private Lane lane2 = new Lane(this);

    // Other things
}
```

Comment: You should be careful about leaking `this` in a constructor.

Comment: What about simply passing road as a parameter in the `go` method?

Comment: That would work as well, but it would make less sense, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

First off `Lane` is not a subclass of `Road`. It does not extend the `Road` class. If you still want to call `switchLane` you can create an instance of `Road`, and then call it's method

```
Road r = new Road();
r.switchLanes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep a reference to the `Road`-parent (I guess `Road` class is in some kind of parent-child relation with `Lane` class):

```java
public class Lane {
    private Road roadParent;
    public void go(){
        driveLane();
        roadParent.switchLanes();
    }
    public void setRoadParent(Road roadParent) {
        this.roadParent = roadParent;
    }
}
```